# Downgrade SharePoint WFE with respect to apps server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation

I am trying to add new WFE to existing SharePoint 2013 farm,For that i installed Prerequisite,SP2013,SP1,CU and language Pack etc...During the installation unfortunately i have installed higher version setup(Language Pack) in my WFE,when 
i run product config wizard,its throwing up message like "`Missing 15.0.4571.1502 version in APPs Server`".To resolve this issue,i have uninstalled higher version in my WFE. Then i ran Product Config wizard,but still its throwing message "`Missing 15.0.4571.1502 version in APPs Serve`r".(Even I restarted the Server after uninstalled 15.0.4571.1502 version in my WFE).

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, you cant uninstall the patches once it installed.
You have to un install the SharePoint then re install it with correct patches.